# Using scope in directive and service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create a developer console in my Angular app and I have the following problem.

On every page of my application I want my developer console to be available (like a floating thing in a corner of the screen). I have HTML template and I am switching content with `ui-view`. My controllers can include `consoleService` and then call something like `myConsole.log(...)`. This function should add message to some array and then display it on web. For my console I have directive with HTML template, where I want to use `ng-repeat` to display all messages.

And now my problem. How should I design this? I was thinking like this:

### First solution

Well, I can create global JS variable, store all messages there and then use `<script>` and write em out in my directive template.

**WRONG!** Not respecting Angular-way of doing things

### Second solution

Ok, I`ll use $scope and put my messages there, and then I can use that magical Angular data bind to just let it work on its own. Ok, but here I have a problem, how can I inject $scope into my service?

**WRONG!** Injecting $scope into service is nonsense, because it would not make any sense, and again, it kinda oppose the Angular-way.

### Third solution

Fine, lets store my messages on console service, since all services in Angular are singletons it should work pretty fine, but... there is no $scope inside a service, so I need to return this array of messages to a controller and then assign it to $scope in controller.

**???** What do you think? My problem with this solution is that in every controller I need to assign message array to $scope and I just dont want to do that, since I need this console everywhere, on every page.

I hope that my explanation of what I want to do is clear, so I am just hoping for a hint, or advice on how to design it in Angular.

Comment: Then instead of `$scope` why not `$rootScope`? If you want to avoid `$rootScope` you can create a top most parent controller as well

Comment: I would use `$rootScope.$emit` to broadcast the messages from the services and have a directive or controller on which I would listen to the broadcasts using `$rootScope.$on`. Or the other way around broadcast from the controllers to the `consoleService`. If you post some code or the structure of your app I could help you easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the third solution. Your service will have an array with all the messages and each controller can use one of it's functions (`service.log(...)`) which will basically just add one message to the service list.

Then on your directive, you just assign the `getMessages` to the directive scope:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.service('log', function(){
  var messages = [];
  return {
    getMessages: function() { return messages; },
    logMessage: function(msg) { messages.push(msg); }
  }
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, log) {
  $scope.msg = '';

  $scope.addMessage = function() {
    log.logMessage($scope.msg);
  };
});

app.directive('console', function(log) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {},
    replace: true,
    template: "<div><div ng-repeat='msg in messages'>{{msg}}</div></div>",
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {
      scope.messages = log.getMessages();
    }
  };
});
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q2g3jBfrlgGQROsTz4Nn?p=preview

Comment: Plunk is not working :( But yeah, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!